# SSRS Default Title Bar

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a dashboard for a client and I want to be able to hide the default control bar at the top of my SSRS Reports. The bar I'm referring to is the bar that allows you to Zoom, Find/Search, Export etc. I'm able to rid the view of the parameters by setting their visibility to false but can't hide the other toolbar at all.

Has anyone ever attempted this? Please can someone point me in the right direction in regards to this so that I can implement and test accordingly.

Thanks all,

Comment: Is this through the Report Manager website? Are you calling a ReportServer URL? Or is this through a web-based or application-based ReportViewer control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the report manager website you can add [&rc:Toolbar=false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) to the URL to hide the toolbar.

If you are using a report viewer control you can set the `ShowToolBar` property to false, e.g.

```
this.ReportViewer1.ShowToolBar = false;
```

Comment: Lovely...I'm gonna bash my ASP guy around a bit now. I changed it and it works 100%. Thank you very much